# uncaught exemption when writing to a static dictionary in an HTTP request

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm getting an Uncaught exemption within a http closure related to a dictionary stating there's an uncaught exemption.  When I set a breakpoint exemptions, it points to a dictionary.  The dictionary in question is declared in a struct as a static var and has multiple values already in it so how can this be happening?  Here's the http request.

```
 session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data,
                let tile = UIImage(data: data),
                let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
                let fileName = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: fileName))


                Maps.tileCachePath[url] = fileName  //<- this is where the exception happens


                //make sure there is no old file and if so delete it
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path){
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)

                    } catch{
                        print("error deleting old tile")
                    }

                }

                //now write the new file
                FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
                print(filePath.path)
                //return
                result(tile, error)

            } else {
                result(nil, error)
            }


            }.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo

Replace

```
Maps.tileCachePath[url] = fileName
```

with

```
Maps.tileCachePath[url] = filePath
```

Basically `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` as a filename is a very bad idea. The number contains fractional seconds which are treated as a file extension.

Use a more reliable file name like a formatted date or at least remove the fractional seconds and add a **real** file extension.

Comment: After trying both solutions (converting the double to a string and replacing the double with an actual file name), I'm still getting a crash.  if I disable the breakpoint for uncaught exceptions,  sometimes it's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, sometimes its an exception.

Comment: not sure if it helps but the exception is 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0):

Date().timeIntervalSince1970 
is a double, you might need a string value there.